# White mold on kale stems

Tags: food-safety, mold, kale

I had kale sitting in the fridge for a few days, and I'm seeing what appears to be white mold on the stems:

[image: white mold on kale stems]

I feel like I've been seeing conflicting reports on the edibility of this online (if I've even properly identified it). Is this type of mold safe to eat? If not, is kale considered a "firm" veggie such that I can cut off an inch or so around it and salvage the rest, or are the leaves too thin to be considered safe once there is a mold infestation on one part of it? The websites I've seen always discuss "firm" vs "soft" veggies, but nothing is said about leafy greens.